# Find previous driver VERSION if 'Rollback driver strong name' missing

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers

I've tackling a random BSOD issue & I updated some drivers (with Dell Command Update), but **I forget to note the previous driver versions which will be helpful to know should the issue re-occur**. Some of the drivers I updated had a 'Rollback driver strong name' which showed the previous driver version, but many did not. Anyway to discover

Windows 10 x64 v1809

Answer (score 0):

Dell Command Update, Activity Log, Export, unzip, open ActivityLog.xml & look for `Install Log Information` under Data look for old version, may have to go to section `--- Start of Vendor Software Log ---`